# What Am I Doing Wrong With This 'Create A View' in My SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, create-view

I am trying to create a view with multiple tables with multiple select statements. The error message I receive is "Incorrect syntax: 'CREATE VIEW' must be only statement in batch."

```
      CREATE Create View V_User_Track_Click_Parse As
      SELECT        Track_Click_1.GUID, 
      Track_Click_1.UserAgent,Track_Click_1.CampaignId 
      FROM          dbo.Track_Click_1  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_1.GUID
      WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_1.UserAgent is not null
      (SELECT        Track_Click_2.GUID, 
      Track_Click_2.UserAgent,Track_Click_2.CampaignId 
      FROM          dbo.Track_Click_2  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_2.GUID
      WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_2.UserAgent is not null)
      (SELECT        Track_Click_3.GUID, 
      Track_Click_3.UserAgent,Track_Click_3.CampaignId 
      FROM          dbo.Track_Click_3  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_3.GUID
      WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_3.UserAgent is not null)
      (SELECT        Track_Click_4.GUID, 
      Track_Click_4.UserAgent,Track_Click_4.CampaignId 
      FROM          dbo.Track_Click_4  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_4.GUID
      WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_4.UserAgent is not null)
      (SELECT        Track_Click_5.GUID, 
      Track_Click_5.UserAgent,Track_Click_5.CampaignId 
      FROM          dbo.Track_Click_5  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_5.GUID
      WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_5.UserAgent is not null)
      (SELECT        Track_Click_6.GUID, 
      Track_Click_6.UserAgent,Track_Click_6.CampaignId 
      FROM          dbo.Track_Click_6  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_6.GUID
      WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_6.UserAgent is not null)
      (SELECT        Track_Click_7.GUID, 
      Track_Click_7.UserAgent,Track_Click_7.CampaignId 
      FROM          dbo.Track_Click_7  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_7.GUID
      WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_7.UserAgent is not null)
     (SELECT        Track_Click_8.GUID, 
     Track_Click_8.UserAgent,Track_Click_8.CampaignId 
     FROM          dbo.Track_Click_8  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Details 
     ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_8.GUID
     WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_8.UserAgent is not null)
     (SELECT        Track_Click_9.GUID, 
     Track_Click_9.UserAgent,Track_Click_9.CampaignId 
     FROM          dbo.Track_Click_9  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Details 
     ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_9.GUID
     WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_9.UserAgent is not null)
     (SELECT Track_Click_10.GUID,
     Track_Click_10.UserAgent,Track_Click_10.CampaignId 
     FROM          dbo.Track_Click_10  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_10.GUID
     WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_10.UserAgent is not null)
     (SELECT        Track_Click_11.GUID, 
     Track_Click_11.UserAgent,Track_Click_11.CampaignId 
     FROM          dbo.Track_Click_11  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_11.GUID
     WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_11.UserAgent is not null)
     (SELECT        Track_Click_12.GUID, 
     Track_Click_12.UserAgent,Track_Click_12.CampaignId 
     FROM          dbo.Track_Click_12  WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     User_Details ON User_Details.GUID = Track_Click_12.GUID
     WHERE User_Details.GUID is Null and Track_Click_12.UserAgent is not null)
```

Desired Output:

Create a View that columns from Track_Click_1 through Track_Click_12's GUID, CampaignId, UserAgent that the GUID is null or does not match the GUID in User_Details. I am trying to create a view for a c# program that pulls all the GUIDs, CampaignIds, and UserAgents from each Track_Click_# table that have not been parsed and put into User_Details table yet.

Table's setup:

```
         Track_Click_1-12
             GUID(uniqueIdentifer,null)
             CampaignId(int,null)
             LinkId(int,null)
             Ip(nvarchar(100),null)
             ClickDate(datetime,null)
             Referrer(varchar(100),null)
             SubId(varchar(100),null)
             UserAgent(varchar(max),null)

          User_Details
             GUID(uniqueIdentifer,null)
             CampaignId(int,null)
             UserAgent(varchar(max),null)
             HardwareType(nchar(10),null)
             SoftwareType(nchar(10),null)
             SoftwareVersion(nchar(10),null)
             OperatingSystem(nchar(10),null)
             DateTime(datetime,null)
```

Comment: The error message generally means you've got another statement in your window.    Perhaps something like    USE <database> then CREATE VIEW (for example).   Make sure the only statement is the create view.    The other option is you've got mismatched parenthesis somewhere and the command thinks the view is complete

Comment: First, get your query to run stand-alone before creating the view; as it stands, your query is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Your view doesn’t contain a single valid SQL statement, it seems to contain multiple unconnected SQL statements.

It’s possible you need to union the various statements together into a single statement in order for this to work

Comment: Yep, there are a bunch of SQL statements glued together there, but they don't make a valid `CREATE VIEW` statement.